# Is it possible to make mplayer from the command line mimic iTunes search

Tags: macos, ubuntu, itunes, mplayer

I recently switched from Mac OSX to Ubuntu and copied all of my music over so it had the iTunes style directory structure and I wanted to be able to type something like:

```
$ music abbey road
```

at the command line and hear the album on shuffle or equivalently

```
$ music beatles
```

and hear all of the music I have by that artist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following zsh function:

```
function music() {
  mplayer $HOME/Music/**/*(#i)("$*")*/**/* -shuffle
}
```

the #i here makes it case insensitive